# Unable to select element in Selenium WebDriver from list box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium Web Driver and unable to select element in the list box and getting below error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ext-element-13"}

```
WebElement item = launch.driver.findElement(By.id("ext-element-13")); 
Select page_dropdown = new Select(item);

for(int i=0; i<page_dropdown.getOptions().size(); i++)
{
    page_dropdown.selectByIndex(i);
    System.out.println("Page drop down having values " + page_dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
}
```

```html
<div id="boundlist-1123" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box" tabindex="-1" style="width: 215px; right: auto; left: 574px; top: 140px; z-index: 19000; height: 300px;" data-componentid="boundlist-1123">
<div id="boundlist-1123-listWrap" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" data-ref="listWrap" style="overflow:     auto; height: 299px;"> 
<ul id="boundlist-1123-listEl" class="x-list-plain" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" role="listbox" data-ref="listEl">
<li id="ext-element-13" class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="3" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC Program : Summary</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="1" data-recordid="4" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC-001: Poor Control</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="2" data-recordid="5" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC-002: Low Density </li>
```

Comment: Below is the code in Selenium Web Driver:
WebElement item = launch.driver.findElement(By.id("ext-element-13"));
Select page_dropdown=new Select(item);  
for(int i=0; i<page_dropdown.getOptions().size(); i++)
{
   page_dropdown.selectByIndex(i);
   System.out.println("Page drop down having values "+page_dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
}

Comment: You should edit the question and add the code to it.

Comment: <div id="boundlist-1123" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box" tabindex="-1" style="width: 215px; right: auto; left: 574px; top: 140px; z-index: 19000; height: 300px;" data-componentid="boundlist-1123">
<div id="boundlist-1123-listWrap" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" data-ref="listWrap" style="overflow: auto; height: 299px;">
<ul id="boundlist-1123-listEl" class="x-list-plain" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" role="listbox" data-ref="listEl">

Comment: <li id="ext-element-13" class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="3" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC Program : Summary</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="1" data-recordid="4" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC-001: Poor Control</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="2" data-recordid="5" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC-002: Low Density </li>

Comment: The error is telling you that there is no element on the page with that ID. If you're sure you have the correct ID, the chances are the page that Selenium is currently on is not the page you expect it to be. Try outputting the page title, or the full page HTML to see what it sees.

Comment: if you have a public URL where you can reproduce this issue, then that will be great

Answer (score 0):

As per provided HTML code, i am expecting it is not Select drop down. so select command may not work here..

secondly if i am correct

```
<ul id="boundlist-1123-listEl" class="x-list-plain" aria-disabled="false" aria-hidden="false" role="listbox" data-ref="listEl">
```

is location of your drop down and below one is one of option correct?

```
<li id="ext-element-13" class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="3" data-boundview="boundlist-1123">ABC Program : Summary</li>
```

here you may need to use sendkeys

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='listbox']")).sendKeys("ABC Program : Summary");
```

you can also use xpath=//*[@data-ref='listEl'] in above code if there are more listbox elements in page

if above one does not work, just try by directly clicking on required option

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'ABC Program : Summary')]")).click();
```

if even above one does not work, then you need to click on ul and then required option.

there may be change in locators, if they are not working let me know, will try for another xpath